# html table not being populated from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I am adapting some scripts that I found through Google that monitor users who login in to a website.

This consists of including this in each page I want to monitor:

```
<?
include_once("config.php"); 
include_once("functions.php"); 
?>
```

config.php looks like this (I have removed info on actual database):

```
<?php 
      DEFINE ('DB_USER', '');// database username 
      DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');//database password 
      DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '');//database host, usually localhost 
      DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '');//and finally the database name 
      $dbc = @mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
      @mysql_select_db (DB_NAME) OR die('Could not select the database: ' . mysql_error() ); 
?>
```

functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$user = $_SESSION["name"];
$logq = "INSERT INTO logs (Name, Page, Date) VALUES ('$user', '$page', NOW())"; 
$logr = @mysql_query($logq); 
?>
```

This works fine, i.e. the table in my database is populated correctly.

However the file that is supposed to generate a table on a webpage to show the information in the MySQL table isn't working.  The file, logs.php, looks like this:

```
<?php 
      $lq = "SELECT id, Name, Page, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d %M, %Y') as sd FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50"; 
      $lr = @mysql_query($lq); 

      if($lr){ 
      echo "<table><th>Name</th><th>Page</th><th>Date</th>"; 
      while($lf = mysql_fetch_array($lr, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
      echo "<tr><td>" . $lf['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $lf['Page'] . "</td><td>" . $lf['sd'] . "</td></tr>"; 
      } 
      echo "</table>"; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
      echo "No results!"; 
      } 
?>
```

Even though there is data in the MySQL table I am always getting just 'No results!' showing when I browse to the page.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: You should remove the `@` and see what it's spitting out. Also, try running the query manually

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Remove the `@` from the mysql_query call, and output possible mySQL errors e.g. using `if (!$lr) trigger_error(mysql_error());`.

Comment: Yes, I do have an "id" column.  Running manually it works fine.  I have removed @ and added `if (!$lr) trigger_error(mysql_error());` but still only 'No results!' shows on the logs.php page

Comment: try simplyfing your query temporarily to select * from order. Also, add quotes round fieldnames, as in 'date'. Field name or a my-sql function?

Comment: If you have PHPMyAdmin try running the query there too, just to check the results

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error()` to make sure it gets output even if error reporting is turned off. (You shouldn't have that in a production environment though - database errors are none of the user's business)

Comment: You are using a mixture of long (<?php) and short (<?) opening php tags,  I'd change them to long opening tags (<?php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have a db connection in logs.php? If your code is the full file then this should be the problem.
If so, just include config.php at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the issue.  There was no mention of this in the original demo page where I got the code from.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can see in your query is that `date` is a reserved word.

You need to wrap that in backticks:

```
"SELECT id, Name, Page, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d %M, %Y')....
```

or rename the column.

This is probably throwing an error in your query that you are not seeing despite the `trigger_error()` recommendation: Error reporting is probably turned off on your server. This is the right behaviour in a production environment, because you don't want the user to see error messages. While developing however, you can activate error reporting to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try do it like this

`$query = "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table><th>Name</th><th>Page</th><th>Date</th>"; 
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Page'] . "</td><td>" . $row['sd'] . "</td></tr>"; 
echo "</table>"; 
}

hope it helps